# Issue with custom UICollectionViewLayout leaving gap at bottom of cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionView with a custom layout.  As seen in the image below there is always a gap between the content and the bottom of the cell.

[image]

Each cell consists of an image and three labels.  I've printed out the size of the of the cell and also printed out the size of the image + the 3 lables and the match, so I have no idea where this extra space is coming from.

```
    let width = columnWidth - cellPadding*2
    let photoHeight = delegate.collectionView(collectionView!, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath: indexPath , withWidth:width)
                print("photo height is: \(photoHeight)")//photo height is: 95.4078125            

    let label1Height = delegate.collectionView(collectionView!, heightForLabel1AtIndexPath: indexPath, withWidth: width)
               print("label1Height is \(label1Height)") // label1Height is 39.0            

    let label2Height = delegate.collectionView(collectionView!,heightForLabel2AtIndexPath: indexPath, withWidth: width) //label2Height is 53.0            
               print("label2Height is \(label2Height)")// label2Height is 53.0       
    let label3Height = delegate.collectionView(collectionView!, heightForLabel3AtIndexPath: indexPath, withWidth: width)

                print("label3Height is \(label3Height)") //label3Height is 135.0            

    let height = photoHeight + label1Height + label2Height + label3Height
                print("total height is: \(height)") //total height is: 322.4078125            

    let frame = CGRect(x: xOffset[column], y: yOffset[column], width: columnWidth, height: height)
                let insetFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: cellPadding, dy: cellPadding)
```

I've pinned the bottom of label3 to the bottom of the cell +4, but that doesn't help